# Supermarket in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, food-and-drink

What are the best-known supermarkets that are in the Netherlands, particularly in the Leiden area? I'm looking for regular grocery stores for food, bread, vegetables, shampoo.

Comment: Why don't you just walk around your neighborhood a bit and find a supermarket that's close to you? Probably more effective then asking here.

Comment: There are plenty. Your question does not make any distinctions from which we can advise one over the other. Note that in The netherlands there are plenty of supermarkets and local shops at short distances; it's not as if you have to decide beforehand with superstore to drive to.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the biggest and probably most famous (in the Netherlands) is [Albert Heijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Heijn) (with their logo being "ah" glued together), which was established in 1887. Looking at the [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_supermarket_chains_in_the_Netherlands), and Gala's comment, I wouldn't presume to list the "top 5", but certainly in addition to Albert Heijn you have PLUS, Jumbo, Lidl, Aldi, SPAR being somewhat frequent in various regions. Most or all of these you should probably find Leiden.

Oh, it looks like there's a [longer list](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_supermarkten#Nederland) on Dutch Wikipedia.